# T-SQL Conditional logic based on Thousandth ( .00X) decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use either Round or Ceiling method based on Thousandth decimal number.
How do I write condition in the T-SQL stored procedure? 
Thanks in advance!

Example:

If I have this number:
1,793.5123611111
I would like to use Round( Variable ,2,1) so that it becomes 1,793.**51**
So that thousandth decimal does not round off.

If I have this number:
11,80620619333

I would like to use ceiling(Variable *100) / 100 so that it becomes 11,806.**21**
So that thousandth decimal rounds off.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current data type? VARCHAR?

You may try this

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100) = '11,806.20619333'

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(@a AS MONEY),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ROUND()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) without a third argument. When the third argument is not specified, it defaults to 0, which means rounding (any other value means truncating):

```
SELECT ROUND(Value, 2)
FROM (
  SELECT 1793.5123611111
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 11806.20619333
) AS s (Value)
;
```

The above will yield these results:

```
--------
1793.51
11806.21
```